# How to use JBuilder outside of Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, jbuilder

I love JBuilder's syntax, and would like to use it outside of rails.  I have a class and and a to_json method:

```
class Blog

  def to_json
    Jbuilder.encode do |json|
      json.(self, :id, :logo)

      json.articles articles do |json, article|
        json.id article.id
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Unfortunately I'm getting:

```
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-0.4.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:13:in `define_method': wrong argument type NilClass (expected Proc/Method) (TypeError)
  from /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-0.4.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:13:in `<class:Jbuilder>'
  from /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-0.4.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

Which corresponds to:

```
# jbuilder.rb
class Jbuilder < BlankSlate
  # Yields a builder and automatically turns the result into a JSON string
  def self.encode
    new._tap { |jbuilder| yield jbuilder }.target!
  end

  define_method(:__class__, find_hidden_method(:class))   # <--- exception
  define_method(:_tap, find_hidden_method(:tap))
  # ....
```

Any idea what gems I need to require in the gem to satisfy JBuilder?

Comment: You can use http://rubygems.org/gems/jbuilder . Include require 'rubygems' and require 'jbuilder' on top of the code

Comment: Starting from a fresh gem with no other dependencies this worked.  Think its probably due to trying to use active recordish models with it, will refactor and see how it goes.  Thanks Shamith.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
template = File.read(template_file)
output = Jbuilder.encode { |json| eval template }
```